# JasperReports: How to define a header in Excel

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I'm cleaning up a legacy application which uses Jasper Reports 3.1.2, and am trying to figure out how to define a header that shows up as the header in the generated Excel spreadsheet (under Page Setup, Header/Footer). The existing code already does this for the footer using:

```
exportParameters.put(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.LEFT_FOOTER, "My footer text");
```

I can't find an equivalent parameter for the header in the JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter class. 
Is there a way to do this in the JRXML template, or via the API ?

Adding a screenshot from the generated Excel report which shows that Excel detects the footer that was defined in the JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter class (code above). I am trying to do the same with the header.

[image]

Comment: For the time being, I'm using the <pageHeader> tag which actually answers most of my use case, i.e. it gets printed on every page. But it does not show up as a header in Excel's Page Setup. That is the one caveat.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot to illustrate what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at **[JasperForge Config Reference](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.header.center)**, the JRXML header and footer properties are not supported until 3.7.5.  In my opinion, it would be easier upgrading to at least version 3.7.5 to accomplish what you're attempting, update your jrxml files, and do regression testing with your existing reports.  If upgrading is not possible and you're familiar with POI or JExcelAPI, I would suggest extending the **[JRXlsExporter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/jasperreports/jasperreports/3.1.2/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter.java?av=f)** or **JRExcelApiExporter** (limited to two links...sorry) and use custom exporter parameters in your API.

The version of Jasper Reports you're using really limits what you can do in excel.  If you do upgrade, you may want to research the XLS properties available in versions above 4.0.  If you're going to be doing more excel specific formatting with your existing reports, it would be more beneficial to uprade to a version higher than 4.0.